# Example of an easy non-pseudotopological convergence

Tags: general-topology, filters

Recently, I have had an introduction to convergence spaces and I was wondering if there is an easy example of a non pseudotopological convergence space.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What precise definitions of _convergence space_ and _pseudotopological space_ are you using?  (There are some variants which will slightly affect the required example.)

Comment: 1,2 is a convergence space, 3 identify a pseudo topology:

1)$\dot x \rightarrow x$

2)If a filter converges, so every finer filter converge

3)lim$\mathcal{F}=\cap_{\mathcal{U} \in \beta \mathcal{F}}$lim$\mathcal{U}$

Comment: I take it that $\dot{x}$ denotes the principal ultrafilter generated by $x$?  (And $\beta \mathcal{F}$ is the family of all ultrafilters finer than $\mathcal{F}$?)

Answer (score -2):

I think the following is the most basic example of a convergence space which is not (equivalent to) a pseudotopological space:

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and fix some $\infty \in X$.  Define a convergence on $X$ so that

- $\dot{x} \rightarrow x$ for each $x \in X$;
- if $\mathcal{U}$ is a free (nonprincipal) ultrafilter on $X$, then $\mathcal{U} \rightarrow \infty$.

(And there are no other convergences.)

It is fairly straightforward to show that this defines a convergence on $X$.  However, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a (free) filter (but not an ultrafilter) on $X$ extending the co-finite filter, then $\mathcal{F} \not\rightarrow \infty$ even though $\mathcal{U} \rightarrow \infty$ for each ultrafilter $\mathcal{U} \supseteq \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Not clear, quite bad